# Rooted Android 10, ioctl Permission denied errors

Tags: android, permission-denied, ioctl, rooted-device

When I try to run some commands on Android 10 (Galaxy A11) with root access, I get the ioctl "Permission denied" errors. For example:

```
# ip tuntap add mode tun
ioctl(TUNSETIFF): Permission denied
# ifconfig wlan0
ifconfig: ioctl 8927: Permission denied
```

and the like.
I tried googling about this issue but couldn't find anything to solve it. Some people talk about SELinux limitations. But [root checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clivin.rootchecker) shows that SELinux status is permissive.
How do I get rid of this `ioctl` errors and get the command line utilities to work properly on my rooted phone?

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by replacing ifconfig script with the following:

Bad command:

`./adb -s $device shell ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`

New command:

`./adb -s $device shell ip addr show wlan0 | grep -e wlan0$ | cut -d " " -f 6 | cut -d/ -f 1`